# How To Maintain Transaction in N-Tier Architecture

Tags: asp.net, architecture, transactions, n-tier-architecture

I am developing application in N-Tier Architecture. as we all know that we need to implement transactions while insert/update/delete operation. please tell me how to use transaction in c#.net in N-Tier architecture.
my architecture is like this
Applicationform->middle_Layre->Factory->DataAccessLayre->StoredProcedure->Table
in application form i create object of middleLayer and pass data in Insert/update/delete function of middle layer.
i am creating object of sqlcommand in factoryclass and fill the data which i gets from middle layer and pass that object os sqlcommand to DAL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a representative pattern of software layers you can follow:

```
Database <-> DAL <-> Repository <-> BLL <-> Controller <-> View Model <-> UI
```

Where

```
DAL == Data Access Layer (aka ORM, Object-Relational mapper)
BLL == Business Logic Layer*
```

In this model, the transaction takes place in the Repository, where a "unit of work" is arranged.  Typically, this happens by requesting data from the DAL, performing work on it, and saving changes.  The DAL will generally wrap a transaction around your unit of work.

The Database, DAL, Repository and BLL collectively form what is known as the Model in MVC (Model-view-controller) architecture.  All business logic and data manipulation takes place in the Model.  The controller acts as a go-between between the model and the View Model/UI, which collectively form the view.

The Repository is where you would set up your "Unit of Work."

*<sub>Optional</sub>

Comment: i am not using MVC architecture.

Comment: i want transaction for multiple operation in same transaction.

Comment: Yes, that's what a "unit of work is."  The MVC architecture is just an illustration.  In short, your transaction should be in the same layer as your business logic.

Comment: Your answer seems to contradict itself.  You said "the transaction takes place in the BLL", but then later you said "The DAL will generally wrap a transaction around your unit of work.   So which is it?  That was the original question. :)  Does the BLL start the transaction, or the DAL?

Comment: @RobertPappas: That's a good question.  You can start a transaction in the BLL, and the DAL (the database, by extension) will maintain that transaction until you commit it.  The DAL *always executes* the transaction, in other words, even if the transaction is started and committed from somewhere else.

Comment: As @RobertPappas points out, this answer is contradictory. The whole point of a DAL is to isolate persistence-related calls to a db from a BLL. Especially when using a proper DAL factory, how do you "maintain that transaction" when the BLL supposedly has no idea what the DAL is up to, and the DAL doesn't know when the BLL begins or ends (starts or commits) its save operations? Or are you suggesting that the bookend calls should belong to the BLL, even though they're bookending an unknown?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thank you, that is a helpful clarification. In that model, is the Repository BLL-aware? Concrete example: if my BLL just runs a lot of C/U/D operations using BLL object attributes as part of a large save transaction--which resolves to a bunch of DAL stored procedure calls--does the Repository "know about" transaction progress, or does it just hold the transaction open for reuse until the BLL announces completion?

Comment: @downwitch: Many applications do not have a formal BLL; the controller talks directly to the repository, which contains some skeleton business logic.  In practice, if you want to take advantage of database transactions, some awareness of the database is unavoidable.

Answer (score 2):

As long as your code is running on the same machine, without any WCF or Web Service calls between the layers, you could use TransactionScope.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx

Just place the calls that you want to occur with a transaction, inside the transaction scope.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to place the logic in a stored procedure. This way your DAL makes a single call to the db that rolls back on failure.